# Vector calculus "identities"

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, divergence-operator, curl

Do these "identities" even make sense? $F$ is a 3D vector field. For the second equation, the LHS is a vector but the RHS is a scalar.
$$\nabla\cdot\Delta F=\Delta(\nabla\cdot F),\,\nabla\times\Delta F=\Delta(\nabla\times F)$$

Comment: Notice that, since $F$ is a vector field, $\Delta$ must be the [vector Laplacial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Vector_Laplacian) both on the LHS and on the RHS.

Answer (score 1):

The first equation means $\partial_i(\partial_j\partial_j F_i)=\partial_j\partial_j(\partial_i F_i)$. The second means $\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j(\partial_l\partial_l F_k)=\partial_l\partial_l(\epsilon_{ijk}\partial_j F_k)$.

Comment: With repeated indices summation convention

Comment: sorry, but I must be misunderstanding something. For the second equation, suppose $F = < f,g,h>$ where $f(x,y,z), g(x,y,z), h(x,y,z)$ are twice differentiable scalar functions, then the curl of the Laplacian of $F$ is a 3-by-1 vector $< \Delta F_y - \Delta F_z, \Delta F_z - \Delta F_x, \Delta F_y - \Delta F_z>$ whereas the Laplacian of the curl of $F$ is $(h_y - g_z)_{xx} + (f_z - h_y)_{yy} + (g_x - f_y)_{zz}$ . The LHS is a vector and the RHS is a scalar, no?

Comment: @user770687 You should actually consider *thrice*-differentiable $f,\,g,\,h$, but the error in your reasoning is that you need the [vector Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Vector_Laplacian), as Gae. S. already noted.

Comment: Thank you, I see that now.